# Java Poi não faz download

Tags: java, microsoft-excel, java-ee, apache-poi

Estou utilizando a biblioteca poi 3.15 para gerar excel em um sistema web, mas estou tendo dificuldade na hora de fazer o download do arquivo, localmente funciona mas quando publico não faz nada.
Coloquei no inicio assim:

```
String  caminho   = System.getProperty("user.home");
String  filename  = caminho + "/arquivo.xls";
```

No final:

```
try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filename)) {
    workbook.write(fileOut);
}
```

e no servlet chamo:

```
case "EXPORTAR":
    new ClasseDAO().exportarExcel(id);
    dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("pagina.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
break;
```

A chamada está na action de um form, ja tentei setando ContentType com vnd.ms-excel, Header com attachment mas não funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode escrever direto na response request.
Ex.:

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=qrquivo.xls");

wb.write(response.getOutputStream());
response.getOutputStream().flush();
```